# A field 'stability' is added in my Parcelable classes

Tags: java, android, parcelable

Here is my class:

```
public class OutstandingContact implements Parcelable {

    public String phoneNumber;
    public String gstIn;
    public String cin;
    public String email;
    public String pincode;
    public String emailCc;
    public List<String> addressList;

    public OutstandingContact() {

    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(this.phoneNumber);
        parcel.writeString(this.gstIn);
        parcel.writeString(this.cin);
        parcel.writeString(this.email);
        parcel.writeString(this.pincode);
        parcel.writeString(this.emailCc);
        parcel.writeStringList(this.addressList);
    }

    protected OutstandingContact(Parcel in) {
        this.phoneNumber = in.readString();
        this.gstIn = in.readString();
        this.cin = in.readString();
        this.email = in.readString();
        this.pincode = in.readString();
        this.emailCc = in.readString();
        this.addressList = in.createStringArrayList();
    }

    public static final Creator<OutstandingContact> CREATOR = new Creator<OutstandingContact>() {
        @Override
        public OutstandingContact createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new OutstandingContact(source);
        }

        @Override
        public OutstandingContact[] newArray(int size) {
            return new OutstandingContact[size];
        }
    };
}
```

While sending this as a body in a server API request (POST) the object 'stability' get added to it automatically. This is not reproducible for my device but users are facing this where the server request validations are failing.

For eg:
The body goes like this:

```
{
    "phoneNumber": "99999999"
    "gstIn": ANDNFJKDNF43848"
    "cin": ""
    "email": abc@whatever.com
    "pincode": "000001"
    "emailCc": ""
    "addressList": []
    "stability": true
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code from where you are calling the API?

Comment: Does interface `Parcelable` have a default method `isStability()` or `getStability()`? Some JSON frameworks like Jackson by default include every method that looks like a getter, even if it returns a calculated value.

Comment: @RobSpoor Yes it does. The Parcelable interface is from the package 'android.os'. And yes we are using com.fasterxml.jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson by default includes each property that has a getter. That includes methods like `isStability()` or `getStability()` - not just methods you define yourself but also inherited methods, and that includes default methods.

Since this `Parcelable` interface isn't yours you cannot annotate this getter with `@JsonIgnore`. You could override it only to add it, but Jackson has a similar annotation you can put on your class: `JsonIgnoreProperties`:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties("stability")
public class OutstandingContact implements Parcelable {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Let me try this and check for a week or two. Thanks for the suggestion. This should work in my opinion

Comment: Its working. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.